# load dynamic data on scroll in Jqgrid

Tags: php, ajax, jqgrid

Where to write an ajax post request to load another set data from db in Jqgrid  on scrolling. I tried by writing request on load complete. I have to load when scroll reaches end

Comment: Do you mean usage of `scroll: 1` option of jqGrid ("virtual scrolling")?

Comment: yes, but i need to post the value of the last row id through ajax